# Find combination of values on same table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Id  Name
1    x
2    y
3    z
```

I want a combination like:

```
Name    Name
x        y
x        z
y        z
```

this combination should be made from the same table.
I tried the query like:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Name
FROM table1 a, table1 b
WHERE a.Id != b.Id;
```

but this produce the result:

```
Name    Name
y        x
z        x
x        y
z        y
x        z
y        z
```

which one is not the exact result.

Comment: Try using `a.Id < b.Id` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `<` instead of `!=`:

```
SELECT 
    a.Name, 
    b.Name
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
    ON a.Id < b.Id
```

---

*Note: [Avoid using the old-style **`JOIN`** syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)*

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id int,name varchar(1))
insert into @t (id,name)values (1,'X'),(2,'Y'),(3,'Z')
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT 
     t1.name,
     t2.name
FROM Cte c
INNER JOIN Cte cc
    ON cc.RN > c.RN
    AND cc.name != c.name
```